# Does atom have undofile feature like vim?

Tags: atom-editor

Vim has feature called `undofile`, in which vim stores changes. It allows to revert changes after a file was closed and opened again. Does atom have similar feature?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no atom does not have this feature, but what you could do is modify the save event to allow you to commit to a github file and then roll back the commits.